# move tiff/tif files having a hyphen in the name

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which moves .tiff/tif files from one folder to another if the filename has digits, for example, 
0000002341567.tif. It is working fine but 
my requirement is to move file even if it has a name like 000000234156-7 or 0000002341567-s
So to say the file name can be suffixed with - and a one digit number or a hyphen and a character.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Documents\Pictures\*.tif*") do (
    if !FileCount! EQU 0 (
        echo Exiting after having moved already %FileCount% TIF files.
        goto LoopEnd
    )
    set "HasOnlyDigits=1"
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%T in ("%%~nI") do set "HasOnlyDigits=%%T"
    if "!HasOnlyDigits!" == "1" (
        move /Y "%%I" "%FolderGood%"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`findstr` has a very limited set of REGEX, but it is enough for this task:

```
@echo off
set filecount=1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%I in ("*.tif*") do (
    if !FileCount! EQU 0 (
        echo Exiting after having moved already %FileCount% TIF files.
        goto LoopEnd
    )
     echo %%~nI|findstr /R "^[0-9][0-9]*-.$" >nul && (
        echo yes %%I
        ECHO move /Y "%%I" "%FolderGood%"
        set filecount+=1
    ) || (
        echo no  %%I
    )
)
:loopend
```

The REGEX here consists of:

`^` Start of the line (string)
`[0-9]` Any digit
`[0-9]*` any digit (zero or any nunmber of any digit)  (previous [0-9] to ensure, there is minimum one digit)
`-` a dash
`.` any character
`$` End of the line (string)